# Android ArrayList ListView/Textview - You must supply a resource ID for a textview

Tags: java, android

I had this working at one point, so I think I'm just referencing something wrong. _regionListView seems to be returning OK. I thought the array inside the ArrayList was the problem as it contained extra null indexes but I think I'm not connecting to the ListView and TextView correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Main.java

```
String _region = inRegion;
    ParserRegion _parserRegion = new ParserRegion();
    InputStream _inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.regions);

    // Parse the Input Stream
    _parserRegion.Parse(_inputStream, _region);

    // Get Regions
    List<PropertiesRegion> _regionList = _parserRegion.GetList();

    // Create the ArrayAdapter
    ArrayAdapterRegion _arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapterRegion(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.search_list, _regionList);

    // Get reference to ListView holder
    ListView _regionListView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.regionListView);

    // Set the ListView adapter
    _regionListView.setAdapter(_arrayAdapter);
```

Search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/search_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selectRegionTextView"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dip"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+android:id/regionListView"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mainMenuButton"
        android:background="@drawable/button_black"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Search_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/regionTextView"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove LinearLayout from search_list.xml and use only textview and put this in textview itself

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

There is no need of LinearLayou there and also you can set **android:layout_height="wrap_content"** .Then it will work. :)

Comment: @user1222760 Sorry!! by mistake i wrote it there.

Answer (score 3):

write your **search_list.xml** like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
```