# Using android developer example 'notepadv3' - how do I add the 'body' value to the Listview?

Tags: android, eclipse

the code in my notes_row.xml file look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
android:minWidth="100dp"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/body" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:fontSize="20dp"/>
```

I get the following error
The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
at line `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

I am hoping someone will be able to help me find success.

Note: I found the code that I copied into this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410267/android-arraylist-listview-textview-you-must-supply-a-resource-id-for-a-textvi).

Comment: You could put them in separate xml files.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but try this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:minWidth="100dp"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:fontSize="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: awesome! that worked perfectly... after I took the android:fontSize="20dp" out