# Android Adapter getView

Tags: android, textview, adapter

Sorry, this issue has been treated several times but I still can not solve it.

I have a Navigation Drawer with Fragment that works fine, but if I use it only with Activity I get error

```
You must supply a resource ID for a TextView.
```

This is my adapter, I do not think anything wrong. Thanks for the help

```
    public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

    public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {       
        return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);


        imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());        
        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());


        return convertView;
    }
  }
```

and XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"  >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
    android:src="@drawable/img_1" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/text1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/icon"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:text="tt"
android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

in my Activity class

```
     mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        //items to array

        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, 0)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, 0)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, 0)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, 0)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, 0)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, 0)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, 0)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, 0)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(8, 0)));
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };


    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Comment: Post your activity class at where you have set adapter for listView.

Comment: specify `id` for `RelativeLayout`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410267/android-arraylist-listview-textview-you-must-supply-a-resource-id-for-a-textvi

Comment: I can not delete the `RelativeLayout` since I have `TextView` and `ImageView`. 
Now place the Activity with the adapter

Comment: @user2867831 try changing the id to something else like textView1 also clean and rebuild the project

Comment: No, unfortunately the same error

Comment: @user2867831 have u used any other Adapter into your code?

Comment: No, only this. Apparently not find the `TextView` since I also added the `ImgaView`. 
Maybe I have to create the layout in a different way? 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

just create a holder class and use textview inside the getview() like this.

```
holder.textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
```

and below class for Holder class.

```
public class Holder {
    TextView textview;
    //CheckBox check;
}
```

Comment: this is will improve performance but what difference would it make with respect to the error op has?